# Acceder con os a carpetas que cambian de nombre en windows según el idioma

Tags: python, rutas

estoy intentando listar todas las carpetas existentes en mi sistema que incluyen ciertos nombres con un script en Python, para esto he creado una función que va recorriendo todos los directorios y encadenando con os.path.join() los nombre de las carpetas que va encontrando.

El problema viene, cuando tras ejecutarlo como administrador al ver con os.listdir('C:\') los archivos existentes en "C:" me detecta "Archivos de programa", pero al intentar acceder de nuevo a ('C:\Archivos de programa') obtengo el error:
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: 'C:\Archivos de programa'

Pero en cambio, al ejecutar la orden os.listdir('C:\Program files') me muestra correctamente los archivos que existen en la carpeta.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me encadene correctamente los nombres?¿Es posible obtener el nombre original de las carpetas directamente en ingles?

Muchas gracias a todos y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui te estas encontrando con dos problemas.

Primero es que windows tiene problemas para asignar/traducir el nombre de estas dichosas carpetas `Program files`, `Program files (86)`, etc... [Ejemplo aqui](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/nombre-de-carpeta-program-files-deberia-ser/1a25f0c1-011d-473d-b301-9bb1e915489a).

Lo segundo es que a la libreria `os`, le cuesta trabajo saber si una ruta es un directorio o un junction. En mi caso, si hago un dir mostrando directorios ocultos me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, el directiorio `Archivos de programa` no es realmente un `<DIR>` sino un `<JUNCTION>`.

Dicho esto, se supone que despues de la version de python 3.5+ la instruccion `os.path.islink()` te deberia dar esta informacion, pero numerosos hilos han que solo obtienen `False` independientemente del directorio con el que usen el metodo.

En tu caso, podrias usar `os.path.realpath()`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo cuando tengas los nombres de los directorios con `os.listdir()`, comprobar que la ruta original coincida con la de realpath y ya decidir que quieres hacer con ella.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta, gracias a ella he conseguido solucionar el problema.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro :)